# PHP Instagram friendships/create/ Error

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I trying to friendships/create/ function in Instagram but I've got some error.

account/login function is working.

**friendships/create Error: "Please update your Instagram app to continue following."**

```
require_once("instagram.php");
$username = '';
$password = '';
$agent = 'Instagram 6.21.2 Android (19/4.4.2; 480dpi; 1152x1920; Meizu; MX4; mx4; mt6595; en_US)';
$guid = GenerateGuid();
$device_id = "android-".$guid;
$data ='{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","username":"'.$username.'","password":"'.$password.'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
$sig    =   GenerateSignature($data);
$data   =   'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';
$login  =   SendRequest('accounts/login/', true, $data, $agent, false);
print_r($login);

/**********

Login working successfully! No problem...

***********/

/*********
But error area is here.
**********/

$device_id = "android-".$guid;
$data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","device_timestamp":"'.time().'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
$sig            =   GenerateSignature($data);
$new_data       =   'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=6';
$follow         =   SendRequest('friendships/create/29180689', true, $new_data, $agent, true);
```

=== instagram.php ===

```
function SendRequest($url, $post, $post_data, $user_agent, $cookies) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://instagram.com/api/v1/'.$url);
/*
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

if($post) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
}

if($cookies) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');            
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
return array($http, $response);
}
function GenerateGuid() {
 return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x', 
        mt_rand(0, 65535), 
        mt_rand(0, 65535), 
        mt_rand(0, 65535), 
        mt_rand(16384, 20479), 
        mt_rand(32768, 49151), 
        mt_rand(0, 65535), 
        mt_rand(0, 65535), 
        mt_rand(0, 65535));
}
function GenerateSignature($data) {
 return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, '25eace5393646842f0d0c3fb2ac7d3cfa15c052436ee86b5406a8433f54d24a5');
}
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line:

```
$data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","device_timestamp":"'.time().'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
```

**to be**

```
$data = '{"user_id":"'.$user_id.'","device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","device_timestamp":"'.time().'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
```

You missed the `user_id` parameter within the request.

Comment: Is the ```$user_id``` the same as ```$username```?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$data ='{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","username":"'.$username.'","password":"'.$password.'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';
```

to

```
$data = '{"user_id":"'.$userId.'","_uuid":"'.$guid.'","_uid":"'.$loggedInUserId.'"}';
```

---

and change this line

```
SendRequest('friendships/create/29180689', true, $new_data, $agent, true);
```

to

```
SendRequest('friendships/create/29180689/', true, $new_data, $agent, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use private APIs, which is not allowed by Instagram's Terms of Use, so only people who works there knew what's missing here.

There're public APIs that can achieve what you wanted to do here: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#post_relationship

Comment: My app is new. So i can't add relationships scope. Do you know a solution for new apps ?

Comment: You have to submit the app for review, then you can use relationships scope. There's no other way around afaik.